# Go Coverage Report Integration with Jenkins

Tags: go, jenkins

I wonder if there's any tool that can convert `go test -coverprofile=cover.out` into the formats that Jenkins can accept?  I found some tools like [go-junit-report](https://github.com/jstemmer/go-junit-report) and [go2xunit](https://bitbucket.org/tebeka/go2xunit), but they actually just convert output from `go test -v`, which is not the coverage report.

I want to know the detailed test coverage in Jenkins directly.  Basically, I want to see the output from `go tool cover -func=cover.out` and `go tool cover -html=cover.out` in Jenkins webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/AlekSi/gocov-xml

This is what we need.  Use Coberuta plugin to generate the coverage profile.

Answer (score 18):

There are several go tools for converting coverage data from `go test` to Cobertura for Jenkins: [gocover-cobertura](https://github.com/t-yuki/gocover-cobertura), or [gocov](https://github.com/axw/gocov/) with [gocov-xml](https://github.com/AlekSi/gocov-xml).

You can use `gocover-cobertura` as follows:

```
$ go get github.com/t-yuki/gocover-cobertura

$ go test -coverprofile=cover.out example.com/demo/...
ok      example.com/demo    0.008s  coverage: 0.0% of statements
ok      example.com/demo/cmd/demo   0.020s  coverage: 23.4% of statements

$ gocover-cobertura < cover.out > coverage.xml

$ head coverage.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE coverage SYSTEM "http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/xml/coverage-04.dtd">
<coverage line-rate="0.35415787" branch-rate="0" version="" timestamp="1520609235359" lines-covered="839" lines-valid="2369" branches-covered="0" branches-valid="0" complexity="0">
        <sources>
                <source>/usr/local/go/src</source>
                <source>/Users/wilfred/workspace/go-scratch/src</source>
        </sources>
        <packages>
                <package name="example.com/demo/cmd/demo" line-rate="0.4848485" branch-rate="0" complexity="0">
                        <classes>
```

Note that you'll need Go 1.10+ to [run `-coverprofile` against multiple packages in one run](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/283558e42b88a6afa39da6ad4ae87558dc053776).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a dedicated plugin for Go coverage reports, nor really for generic code coverage.

For reports like this, I use the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) to publish `.html` files created during a build.

Comment: I just found https://github.com/AlekSi/gocov-xml, I think it will do what we need!

Comment: Ah, nice. Good to know!